# how to run commandline in electron after build with ASAR

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process, electron-builder

child_process code like bellow

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.execFile(path.join(__dirname,'./run/start.bat'))
```

i have config in package.json like this

```
"extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./run",
        "to": "run"
      }
    ],
```

after build with electron-builder, in folder resources i have 2 file electron.asar and app.asar and folder run. but it not execFile start.bat after build. running in dev is working good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
? path.join(__dirname,'./run/start.bat')
: path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'run/start.bat');
```